# Error:(198) *** Android NDK: Aborting... . Stop.Error:Execution failed for task ':prjectLibaryName:compileReleaseNdk'

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to merge an old project(non-gradle) with a new project(gradle) in Android Studio.
I tried to define the old project () as a Library and set it as a dependency in my project.

my app build.gradle:

[image]

my libary `ZAndUtil` build.gradle:

[image]

at gradle.properties I added `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true`
at settings.gradle I added `include ':app', ':ZAndUtil'`

at local.properties I added `ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Dvir\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Dvir\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk`

I cannot sync my project and I get this Error:

```
C:\Users\Dvir\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\add-application.mk
Error:(198) *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
:ZAndUtil:compileReleaseNdk FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':ZAndUtil:compileReleaseNdk'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Dvir\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd'' finished 
with non-zero exit value 2
```

Thanks for helps

Comment: Fix!!!   ZAndUtil build.gradle :  'jni.srcDirs = []' ,'compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"'  .  my app build.gradle: 'compileSdkVersion 23','buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"'

Comment: Please check this post. it may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47197151/4549220